# Enumeration order and citation format in APA style

Tags: bibtex, enumerate, apacite

I am using APA style for citation.

```
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{url}
```

These is my .bib file:

```
@article{Li2017,
author = {Li, Xu and Wang, Wenqi and Chen, Junjie},
doi = {10.1007/s11427-017-9175-2},
issn = {1869-1889},
journal = {Science China Life Sciences},
mendeley-groups = {thesis},
number = {10},
pages = {1093--1113},
title = {{Recent progress in mass spectrometry proteomics for biomedical research}},
volume = {60},
year = {2017}
}


@article{HE201539,
title = "Data Mining for Bioinformatics Applications. 5 - Protein inference in shotgun proteomics",
editor = "Zengyou He",
publisher = "Woodhead Publishing",
pages = "39 - 49",
year = "2015",
isbn = "978-0-08-100100-4",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-100100-4.00005-3",
author = "Zengyou He"
}
```

In the document, they go in this order.

```
text1 \shortcite{Li2017}. text2 \shortcite{HE201539}
```

But in references, they go in a reversed mode.

[image]

I tried to apply `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` but it didn't work for me.

Comment: `apacite` implements the citation/reference style mandated by the APA. As such the reference list is always sorted by author names and year and not by the order entries are cited in the document. From what I can see this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Unsorted bibliography styles are almost always numeric styles otherwise finding citations becomes a nightmare. So either you want numeric citations and an unsorted and numbered bibliography or you want author/year citations with a sorted bibliography.  Also the `apacite` package should be used *only* with the `apacite` bibliography style.

Comment: Ok, so what would I choose then to have references in the format like [1] and enumerated list in references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, APA style is not supposed to be sorted by the order of appearance in the text. 
So, I applied `\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}` and made the following corrections:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{references} % enumerated reference list
```

Now using `text1 \cite{Li2017}. text2 \cite{HE201539}` it worked out.

[image]

[image]